# How to Create a Model Which Can Produce Accurate Predictions?

Tags: regression, logistic, linear-model

My code and output are attached below. I create a simulation dataset with only 2 categorical features (each has values of 0 or 1). The labels (0 or 1) for each categorical combination are generated according to Bernoulli trials with a pre-defined success probability. Then I fit the dataset with a logistic regression model. But I found the prediction probability for each combination is not close to the pre-defined success probability (i.e, 0.1 vs 0.076). I tried linear regression and got the similar result. For such a simple dataset, I don't think fitting a non-linear model is necessary. My question is: is there any way to improve the probability prediction using linear models?

````
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model

# Create a simulation dataset with 2 features and dummy encoding
np.random.seed(2000)
n_samples = 1000
p1, p2, p3, p4 = 0.10, 0.30, 0.20, 0.70
data = []
ys = []
# For x1=0, x2=0, generate 1,000 records with 0/1 label via bernouli trial of p=0.1
for i in range(n_samples):
    y = np.random.binomial(1, p1)
    ys.append(y)
    data.append([y,0,0])
    avg_y1 = np.mean(ys)

print("p1:{:.2f}, avg_y1:{:.3f}".format(p1, avg_y1))

ys = []
# For x1=0, x2=1, generate 1,000 records with 0/1 label via bernouli trial of p=0.3
for i in range(n_samples):
    y = np.random.binomial(1, p2)
    ys.append(y)
    data.append([y,0,1])
    avg_y2 = np.mean(ys)

print("p2:{:.2f}, avg_y2:{:.3f}".format(p2, avg_y2))

ys = []
# For x1=1, x2=0, generate 1,000 records with 0/1 label via bernouli trial of p=0.2
for i in range(n_samples):
    y = np.random.binomial(1, p3)
    ys.append(y)
    data.append([y, 1,0])
    avg_y3 = np.mean(ys)

print("p3:{:.2f}, avg_y3:{:.3f}".format(p3, avg_y3))

ys = []
# For x1=1, x2=1, generate 1,000 records with 0/1 label via bernouli trial of p=0.7
for i in range(n_samples):
    y = np.random.binomial(1, p4)
    ys.append(y)
    data.append([y, 1,1])
    avg_y4 = np.mean(ys)

print("p4:{:.2f}, avg_y4:{:.3f}".format(p4, avg_y4))

d1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['y','x1','x2'])
X = d1[['x1','x2']]
y = d1.y
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True).fit(X, y)

print("p1:{:.2f}, avg_y1:{:.3f}, pred_p1:{:.3f}".format(p1, avg_y1, clf.predict_proba(np.array([[0,0]]))[0][1]))
print("p2:{:.2f}, avg_y2:{:.3f}, pred_p2:{:.3f}".format(p2, avg_y2, clf.predict_proba(np.array([[0,1]]))[0][1]))
print("p3:{:.2f}, avg_y3:{:.3f}, pred_p3:{:.3f}".format(p3, avg_y3, clf.predict_proba(np.array([[1,0]]))[0][1]))
print("p4:{:.2f}, avg_y4:{:.3f}, pred_p4:{:.3f}".format(p4, avg_y4, clf.predict_proba(np.array([[1,1]]))[0][1]))

print("coef:{}, intercept:{}".format(clf.coef_, clf.intercept_))
#p1:0.10, avg_y1:0.118, pred_p1:0.076
#p2:0.30, avg_y2:0.289, pred_p2:0.332
#p3:0.20, avg_y3:0.195, pred_p3:0.238
#p4:0.70, avg_y4:0.698, pred_p4:0.653
#coef:[[1.33225542 1.79422588]], intercept:[-2.49334945]
```
````

Comment: What are `ap1` through `ap4`? They're not defined in your code

Comment: @alanocallaghan I corrected the error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: By the way, your code does a lot of "growing objects", ie appending to vectors. This isn't necessary here and is likely to result in slow code as objects have to be copied around memory in order to find free space to add the extra data.

Answer (score 1):

The baseline probability when $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both zero is 0.1. $x_2$ adds 0.2, $x_1$ adds 0.1, while $x_1$ and $x_2$ together adds 0.6. This implies that the effect of $x_1 + x_2$ is not additive (ie, the effect of $x_1$ with $x_2$ combined is greater than their individual effects combined). You need an interaction term to model this.

I'm more of an R user than Python but I hope this is legible. The result is still not exact (probably just sampling error). The interaction term is highly significant. Further, you can also see with the likelihood ratio test that the interaction term significantly improves the model fit.

```r
## Your data after saving with pd.to_csv
data <- read.csv("/tmp/scratch/mydata.csv")
data[[1]] <- NULL

## GLM (logistic) with no interaction
mod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, family = binomial(link="logit"))
## Interaction model
mod_int <- glm(y ~ x1 * x2, data = data, family = binomial(link="logit"))

## Full model summary
summary(mod_int)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = y ~ x1 * x2, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
#>     data = data)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
#> -1.5475  -0.8259  -0.5011   0.8480   2.0674  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept) -2.01151    0.09802 -20.521  < 2e-16 ***
#> x1           0.59366    0.12641   4.696 2.65e-06 ***
#> x2           1.11126    0.12031   9.237  < 2e-16 ***
#> x1:x2        1.14437    0.15997   7.154 8.44e-13 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 5044.6  on 3999  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 4140.2  on 3996  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 4148.2
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

## Predictions for permutations of covariate values
predict(mod_int, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 0, x2 = 0), type = "response")
#>     1 
#> 0.118
predict(mod_int, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 0, x2 = 1), type = "response")
#>     1 
#> 0.289
predict(mod_int, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 0), type = "response")
#>     1 
#> 0.195
predict(mod_int, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 1, x2 = 1), type = "response")
#>     1 
#> 0.698

## Likelihood ratio test
anova(mod, mod_int, test = "LRT")
#> Analysis of Deviance Table
#> 
#> Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2
#> Model 2: y ~ x1 * x2
#>   Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance  Pr(>Chi)    
#> 1      3997     4190.1                          
#> 2      3996     4140.2  1    49.83 1.677e-12 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I have another minor question. Since I used dummy encoding here, so I have to use an intercept term. How to explain this(need to use an intercept term) from theoretical point of view?

Comment: You don't need to use an intercept with dummy encoding, I don't know why you'd think that. In this case an intercept certainly helps. An intercept in general is the predicted value when all predictors are zero.

Comment: When I use clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y), the prediction for x1=0, x2=0 becomes p1:0.10, avg_y1:0.118, pred_p1:0.500.

Comment: If there's no intercept, when all covariates are zero the predicted value is zero. Zero transformed with the logistic function is 0.5.

Comment: That is what I meant. I have to add an intercept term for dummy encoding in order to get accurate predictions.

Comment: That's not due to the fact that you used dummy variables, it's just because of the relationship between predictors and outcome. You can make a theoretical point about this, but if you're talking about predictive accuracy it's perhaps more important to reason about what your model specification means mathematically (same goes for the lack of an interaction term).

Comment: If you plot the probabilities that you're seeking to model it's very clear that an additive model cannot possibly capture them, and that an interaction term is necessary to get accurate predictions.

Comment: By the way I'd encourage you to accept and upvote my answer if I've answered your questions.

Comment: If I just want to have 2 features/columns and not use intercept, what other encodings can I consider to get accurate predictions?

Comment: If the data do not contain a global offset, ie a non-zero value when all predictors are zero, you do not need an intercept in a model to obtain accurate predictions. This is independent of the encoding of the variables. For example, for a linear model, if the outcome was standardised (zero mean, unit variance) you would not need an intercept term.

Comment: Your answers are great and extremely helpful! I learned a lot from them. Obviously I need to improve my knowledge about Linear Models. Can you suggest some resources on this(books, papers, articles, etc) which cover what you said here?

Comment: I think Introduction to Statistical Learning is a great resource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108823/discussion-between-taichuang-and-alan-ocallaghan).